# Python Selenium Having Issues Selecting From Dropdown

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have no training in python and am trying to write my first script using Python Selenium via Visual Studio Code. I'm currently trying to select an item from a dropdown box, but I'm not understanding how this html was put together, it feels pretty unconventional.

I want to select A-Active from the Status dropdown box:

[image]

However, when inspecting the code for the dropdown box it's not using a Select tag. When I copy outerHTML this is all I get back:

```
<div class="g_GridElement g_GridElement_scrollignore gl_94_x_97 gl_94_w_97_12 gl_94_y_1 gl_94_h_1_1">
    <div class="containerElement gbc_WidgetBase gbc_ComboBoxWidget gbc_MunisComboBoxWidget w_111 g_measureable gbc_WidgetBase_standalone aui__1107 gbc_NotNull gbc_Required gbc_Focus editing" tabindex="0" role="combobox" __widgetbase="" __comboboxwidget="" __muniscomboboxwidget="" id="w_111" data-aui-id="1107" aria-expanded="false" aria-live="polite" aria-owns="w_113" aria-labelledby="w_112" data-gqa-name="prempmst.prem_act_stat" data-gqa-aui-id="1107" data-gqa-tabindex="7" data-aui-name="prempmst.prem_act_stat" aria-describedby="tcw-tooltip-22" aria-selected="true">
        <tcw-text-field density="dense" class="gbc_dataContentPlaceholder gbc_WidgetBase gbc_EditWidget gbc_MunisEditWidget w_112 g_measureable gbc_WidgetBase_standalone gbc_staticMeasure aui__1107" __widgetbase="" __editwidget="" __muniseditwidget="" id="w_112" data-aui-id="1107" tcw-text-field-label-floating="">
            <input type="text" class="gbc-label-text-container tyl-text-field__input--focused" autocomplete="new-password" __widgetbase="" __editwidget="" __muniseditwidget="" id="input-w_112" readonly="readonly">
            <label __widgetbase="" __editwidget="" __muniseditwidget="" for="input-w_112" slot="label" class="tyl-floating-label tyl-text-field__label--focused tyl-floating-label--float"></label>
            <char-measurer class="g_layout_charMeasurer" aria-hidden="true">
                <char-measurer-item class="g_layout_charMeasurer1">
                    MMMMMMMMMM
                    M
                    M
                    M
                    M
                    M
                    M
                    M
                    M
                    M
                </char-measurer-item><char-measurer-item class="g_layout_charMeasurer2">0000000000</char-measurer-item>
            </char-measurer><span class="gbc_dataContentMeasure" aria-hidden="" __leaflayoutmeasureelement="">B - BENEFITS ONLY</span><i slot="trailing" class="tyler-icons" aria-hidden="true">arrow_drop_down</i>
        </tcw-text-field><i class="zmdi toggle" title="Open list" __widgetbase="" __comboboxwidget="" __muniscomboboxwidget=""></i>
        <char-measurer class="g_layout_charMeasurer" aria-hidden="true">
            <char-measurer-item class="g_layout_charMeasurer1">
                MMMMMMMMMM
                M
                M
                M
                M
                M
                M
                M
                M
                M
            </char-measurer-item><char-measurer-item class="g_layout_charMeasurer2">0000000000</char-measurer-item>
        </char-measurer><div tabindex="0" class="gbc_dataContentPlaceholder mt-label gbc_WidgetBase gbc_LabelWidget gbc_MunisLabelWidget w_114 g_measureable tyl-typography--caption gbc_WidgetBase_standalone gbc_staticMeasure aui__1107" role="note" __widgetbase="" __labelwidget="" __munislabelwidget="" id="w_114" data-aui-id="1107">
            <span class="gbc-label-text-container is-empty-label" __widgetbase="" __labelwidget="" __munislabelwidget=""></span>
            <char-measurer class="g_layout_charMeasurer" aria-hidden="true">
                <char-measurer-item class="g_layout_charMeasurer1">
                    MMMMMMMMMM
                    M
                    M
                    M
                    M
                    M
                    M
                    M
                    M
                    M
                </char-measurer-item><char-measurer-item class="g_layout_charMeasurer2">0000000000</char-measurer-item>
            </char-measurer><span class="gbc_dataContentMeasure" aria-hidden="" __leaflayoutmeasureelement=""></span>
        </div><tcw-tooltip target="#w_111" text="Active Status from employee master" style="border: 0px; clip: rect(0px, 0px, 0px, 0px); height: 1px; margin: -1px; overflow: hidden; padding: 0px; position: absolute; width: 1px; outline: 0px; appearance: none;" id="tcw-tooltip-22">Active Status from employee master</tcw-tooltip>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's not even showing all the options, just the first two. Has anybody come across html like this? Any ideas on how I can select A for the Status box? I feel like I'm not giving y'all enough to work with, but I'm not sure what else to provide...

Comment: IF is not a select you can not use it in the same way you use a select element. So you can make click into the select and then wait for the element of the list you want to select, and then click on the element once is shown in the page.

Comment: unfortunately, it's hard to suggest based on the detail you have here, either share the URL, or save `driver.page_source` as HTML file and then share that HTML.

Comment: As previously, this question is missing basic debugging details

Comment: @simpleApp I did as suggested and tried to save the html, but when writing it it produced the error: Exception has occurred: UnicodeEncodeError 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\ue8b8' in position....  I was able to copy the variable and save it to an html page that way, which can be found at https://assessment.jefferson.kyschools.us/DMC/test.html.  The new issue though is that what was copied isn't even close to what the page I'm trying to scrape looks like.

Comment: sorry, cant access the page, getting connection time out.